# Login destination to file download - prompt user

Tags: files

we have some private file links that are pasted into emails. When a user clicks the link, if they are not logged in they get something like this:

http://mysite.com/user/login?destination=/system/files/private/myfile.docx

Once they login and authenticate, the file starts to download in the user's browser.

I'd like to override the automatic download behavior and provide a "download this file?" type prompt first, since users don't often realize the file download starts automatically.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few ways you could handle this. All of them are going to involve some code to handle these type of requests. One way I can think of would be to catch these requests on your custom 404 page and redirect the user to the login page with a new destination and keep the file name as a parameter. Then, on the new destination page grab the file download parameter and provide them a big fat button that links to that file.

If they are already logged in and you want to do the same thing you would need some sort of pre-processing filter to capture these and do the same as above.